# Problems with read data in R

Tags: r, statistics

I usually enter data into R by hand, but I have this data set with n=27 elements. I read the data with `data = read.table("HW6.txt", header = TRUE)` The working environment shows the data there, `X=23,19,...` and `Y=27.1,22.1,...`

I can get my least squares just fine:

```
results=lm(Y~X, data) and 
lm(formula = Y ~ X, data = data)

# Coefficients: (Intercept) X
# 1.800 1.004
```

But for whatever reason I make calls to X or Y to do further manipulation, i.e.

```
sum(X) 
# Error: object 'X' not found,
```

or

```
mean(X) 
# Error in mean(X) : object 'X' not found
```

So, is there something else I have to do to get it to work properly?

Comment: Try `with(data, mean(X))`.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have helped.

Comment: when doing `read.table`, `X` and `Y` should not be defined. What do you mean by "The working environment shows the data". does `get("X", envir=.GlobalEnv)` return something?

Comment: @RockScience I was wondering the same.

Comment: `mean(data$X)` is several characters shorter than using `with` and is more R-ish and less likely to introduce bugs. For example, if there is no `X` in your data frame `d`, but there is an `X` in your workspace from earlier, you'll get the mean of that `X`, and no warning or error. Don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enter data "by hand" into R, you're creating variables in the `.GlobalEnv`, i.e. the workspace that you encounter when you open R.

When you instead load data into R using `read.table`, etc. you are creating a data.frame where those variables are stored. As @Amrita's answer shows you, you can then extract variables from that data.frame using `[` or `$` extraction.

Thus an option for you (i.e., the option that will create behavior most similar to your previous workflow) is the following:

```
d <- read.table("HW6.txt")
X <- d$X
Y <- d$Y
rm(d)
```

Then you can just refer to the variables as `X` and `Y` without having to do any of the things I described earlier.

But! It's probably just better to correct your workflow and start using `$` extraction from a data.frame rather than fall back on the convenience of what you've been doing previously.

(Note 1: In an interactive session, you can also use `with(data, ...)` to execute expressions using objects from your data.frame without using `$` or `[` extraction. It's generally discouraged to use this in a script/package/etc.)

(Note 2: To recreate the behavior you're used to, you can use `attach(data)`, which will add the data.frame to R's search path. This is discouraged, though, because it can have unintended consequences. Among these, if you modify `X` in the .GlobalEnv, it does not modify it in the original data.frame, thus creating confusion later one if you try to call either object.)

Comment: No, don't use `with` or `attach` unless you absolutely have to. Sometimes the best thing is to change your previous workflow and learn a new paradigm. In this case its as simple as learning that you've read in a "data frame" and you should learn about those.

Answer (score 7):

Individual elements can be accessed as below

```
data = read.table("HW6.txt", header = TRUE)
data$X
sum(data$X)
```